# ngx-daterangepicker displaying wrong value with UTC timezone

Tags: timezone, utc, daterangepicker, angular-daterangepicker, ngx-daterangepicker-material

Version of ngx-daterangepicker is displaying wrong value while using UTC timezone. This is what value picker is showing: **2/05 02:50 PM** and this is value i send to picker: **Mon Feb 05 2024 13:50:13 GMT+0000** . Is there any solution for this problem? Can somebody help?

I have found that they are having this issue since September of 2023. but until now no solution. Link for bug on git is [here](https://github.com/fetrarij/ngx-daterangepicker-material/issues/533):